# Join two lottie json file parts into one manually using notepad

Tags: json, merge, notepad, manual

Is it the case you can copy and paste the contents of the second part to the end of the first and remove the middle code, whichever part/s of the below information provided>?  And what if the two starts are then identical keys? What would need to be replaced to make the combined valid and playable?

The start of the first file

{"v":"5.7.8","fr":30,

The end of the first file

,"bm":0}],"markers":[]}

The start of the second

{"v":"5.7.8","fr":30,

The end of the second file

,"bm":0}],"markers":[]}

Answer (score -1):

you can mix layers[] of json files